# Convert arrays to nested objects javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, arrayobject

I have a array of objects, like this:

```
var tryArray = [{
  name: 'name1',
  subname: 'subname1',
  symbolname: 'symbol1'
},
{
  name: 'name1',
  subname: 'subname11',
  symbolname: 'symbol11'
},
{
  name: 'name2',
  subname: 'subname2',
  symbolname: 'symbol2'
},
{
  name: 'name2',
  subname: 'subname22',
  symbolname: 'symbol22'
},
{
  name: 'name3',
  subname: 'subname3',
  symbolname: 'symbol3'
},
{
  name: 'name3',
  subname: 'subname33',
  symbolname: 'symbol33'
}];
```

I want to convert this array into a nested object, where the name will be parent of subname, and subname will be parent of symbolname. For example:

```
result = {
  name1: {
    subname1: [symbolname1],
    subname11: [symbolname11] 
  },
  name2: {
    subname2: [symbolname2],
    subname22: [symbolname22] 
  },
  name3: {
    subname3: [symbolname3],
    subname33: [symbolname33] 
  }
}
```

I have tried using reduce like this

```
tryArray.reduce((object, item) => {
   object[item.name] = {[item.subname]: [item.symbolname]}
},{})
```

but it returned only one subname. any ideas how to resolved this, thank you so much

Comment: thank you vijay, but map is always return array value, but i need object as a returned value

Comment: you have to return the object `object[item.name] = {[item.subname]: item.symbolname};return object;` and don't wrap item.symbolname in blocks []

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`reduce` expects a return value like:

```js
var tryArray = [{"name":"name1","subname":"subname1","symbolname":"symbol1"},{"name":"name1","subname":"subname11","symbolname":"symbol11"},{"name":"name2","subname":"subname2","symbolname":"symbol2"},{"name":"name2","subname":"subname22","symbolname":"symbol22"},{"name":"name3","subname":"subname3","symbolname":"symbol3"},{"name":"name3","subname":"subname33","symbolname":"symbol33"}]

var result = tryArray.reduce((object, item) => {
  object[item.name] = object[item.name] || {}; //Need to init name if not exst
  object[item.name][item.subname] = [item.symbolname];
  return object;
}, {})

console.log( result );
```

---

If you have multiple `symbolname`s in a `subname`, you can:

```js
var tryArray = [{"name":"name1","subname":"subname1","symbolname":"symbol1"},{"name":"name1","subname":"subname11","symbolname":"symbol11"},{"name":"name2","subname":"subname2","symbolname":"symbol2"},{"name":"name2","subname":"subname22","symbolname":"symbol22"},{"name":"name3","subname":"subname3","symbolname":"symbol3"},{"name":"name3","subname":"subname33","symbolname":"symbol33"}];

var result = tryArray.reduce((object, item) => {
  object[item.name] = object[item.name] || {}; //Need to init name if not exist
  object[item.name][item.subname] = object[item.name][item.subname] || []; //Need to subname name if not exist
  object[item.name][item.subname].push(item.symbolname); //Push the symbolname
  return object;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: can you please help me what if there are multiple symbolnames for 1 subname and i want to make it as an array of symbolnames